# Using Google Image Search programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, google-image-search

I'm creating a Windows Phone 7 app, in which I take a picture from my phone and have to upload it on google image search.

Here is the flow which I have understood till now.

We have to post image as a byte[] to url: https://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload

Params are:

```
image_url

btnG    Search
encoded_image   ÿØÿà�JFIF��H�H��ÿá¡Exif��MM�*������������������b�������j(�������1�������r2�������i����������È���H������H���Adobe Photoshop 7.0�2007:08:06 11:06:10���� ����ÿÿ�� ������w ��������������������������������(�������������&������s�������H������H���ÿØÿà�JFIF��H�H��ÿí�Adobe_CM�ÿî�Adobe�d���ÿÛ��      ÿÀ���x"�ÿÝ��ÿÄ?���������� ��������� �3�!1AQa"q2¡±B#$RÁb34rÑC%Sðáñcs5¢²&DTdEÂ£t6ÒUâeò³ÃÓuãóF'¤´ÄÔäô¥µÅÕåõVfv¦¶ÆÖæö7GWgw§·Ç×ç÷�5�!1AQaq"2¡±B#ÁRÑð3$bárCScs4ñ%¢²&5ÂÒDT£dEU6teâò³ÃÓuãóF¤´ÄÔäô¥µÅÕåõVfv¦¶ÆÖæö'7GWgw§·ÇÿÚ���?�ó-©mDÙnÓz&>-ýn33³2*él°ÐÊèvæÕwPÉkk­ÈwóxxÞ«ùûëþm9kÏ&>Ô³çìyqÏ¡Sìÿ�ÏMr×¯ë&E ¯ö~OéÎ¯Qe8­¶Ãÿ�¡LçÛþjg]ë@=¹ÝG+!}O¹þÿ�¬1Í£ÿ�I4¿üÍël9íÇé¼Nüìh *Xì¯ü!Ðº%L?jëm¶Àtf5¹�øü¿Ù´ÿ�ÕªcXaÔã½ÓÃYü÷mgý$G2ÊÝ¶ÀÐï½è¹íjJm²¯ªÔ8áfçG'#&¼fúÆ%VìÚÿ�æÖPÛÓ_ÓAÿ�µX\Y§Ó·5¶}¥úO®k?qQHiM^­Ò2ºNiÄÉÚâZÛiº³º»jxÝNN=á)µ¿úMSÚºÜÖ·«}H¦öÙ?Vï8öÆ³wã½çþÿ�Ð3úÚíKj&Ô¶¤{RÚµ-©)Ô6¤ÿÐàpv)³ù±}Eÿ��öî[_EgauB nf?£cûðÞü³û5Ñwý}c�ææèæGÄÁuWááõCò·zóqò-²§5¯e9Á¸»=@ö~'§¿èÿ�ÚäkÑkI \t ¹«ÓèúõSà;»la!ßk²ËÉ�þíNÃ¡ú_àm[Ý>ü<Qc:UãO²ºê¬°ýæ6¯Þÿ� úDî vÙAò_«Ý84ÕÓòÈÙs}*Àó¹fªöµÞµºoÔ^©h¥ÙxxÏÛêl2íÛñ«~7¹VúëûNû±bô¢Ë@9wWµ®%­·ÞZæ»ØÆµÛ~Û7!75×Ê+¿)èX@=¶måíGHâ?ø´éuöÞ­mÿ�¼Ìj_Ë}½h7ê×Ôì~­I~Sq-�e@¶¦»~×ÿ�6µëéýføÛ]#OvEÓÈ¬Ù·üÅ!õ6ë]Ya¶W;MMp#pÅ¾£?ê£WúÉê|ËdrW /ë|®#ÿ�g[VZÊ¨êTYÒó+4néwú5¿£È®üz¿á3?^wÒ¾­õ>¥vmmoÃqfeÖYiu~ècÞÇúU3ÞõëýCêVzVS0þÝ³ÔÅ±Îâú¿ÞÀßðõ³é®_öväÛ}�2®¦Öu6j >»,cÜßÏÅº«1?ë*bPó"\îk/ðùLRG)CSÃzÿ�åßþ.qÅ;qz¡~d­¶ ÚïÌ¯s,uïw·Ôý2â¶Hp-p$9§Fk¿ª»×çÛë¶®áùWæÛu¬Ë,{Ú<ç9ª<32»èÍÍ`>ó^M}©mDÚÕ+UÔ6¤ÿÑá6®êûkÎ£öu ä×oO%úö,Â·úÍêttÖ,=ª÷H²Ú¯x¨ih}Qþ§qÿ�Í»ÓöAú½Ò­ë]'ª;¨Ña­â*½ßÑ=¿§gÐkÖ>¯ôÌ\e¹o{¬±¢*q<¾ËAkýú{îAú_­Õ±X×w__SÃ%»AÔ«ûk+c~Ú.õªö~zë[hq:Ã´?0Ë3ú_fgúbôÌJ#ô·X^fu}{j}gîo¶ì-­ÞR?Îxkw:ß¦Në×Á(>?r¡w\éµ>¶µÎcS]g¹ugÒÙgékúh#«u7JÈ3©õÝ]1Ïmö%Ju! ëø¯)úÑÓzMÑÂ½×ãõn¢]ycvæñº>]~ïôËÕ¥£Ár^ñkfONêV4}ÒþH×ÓÉÚükáùfQ_ý¼;¯Ç> vx[³ü¯§[¬ïÑ×ÿ�MëµéßWp.Â£{ßYy-®£°ÃSî³Üíßá=&,®·õr*ßy»ÛU±êVÒCwµ·×¸ûýÙ_ü"¢^¤¶9¸ÎGGûåçö¥µj[Tí4[REÚJÿÒãÛ[æ±.{Èkâvµ­þ²ÙU¾°áúyY{k±¯±­üòkoÒÚßô^¢­ÑkêØAeä»qí»é&dÈbElF@I'ziýYÊv_é»Ú@°åt^_ú0×më]+Ûý|Ì?âW¡nÉtEl¯ÍîÜGÉ¿ù%åù°UÔë­¡×ôóOYÁ.vØ8õígò¿V»3þÛ^Êsú,ÉÇêF¬<¦iôª`§kw³ôÏõ>]ú=ÿ�?ùºL%ÅY#ìlÙf[.¶²¦oÇcXâÂâçn{\ö¶íÞý¿èÐÛÐ:g¨ûn¤dØ÷9ÅÙÛËÿ�N§þûÿ�À±ªÄÈ£>ûècë-º×8ê5Ó´ú~«sYîÿ�Ôw}vSX9V±»sí¿ç©ªÕ/F=8õ©h­�´@[?Í­b ÷7íLÄôì±±¤ÂÆ¾'÷}F Yõ¦4í­îÈy;vÔÒí{ öµeõLüÜ)¶¬3Cñ-&û[Q5=¶Wk6¿ó¬©¶»nïð^ô(¦ÛtõºlÃûuy®¬§bå×qh}f»NÛVæ±Ì·Ó»ÿ�½XúÉÒÇWèY½:aùKµ¿¤Æö2[Ö3ñ¬³$5 31æÌØZÜwVãú7zt5µÅw!]·ô9æcá?E4È¾8ÉÝó<^­e¢Ç{]i.-�â7ºö½ýµXéýBßµ±Ä2}Ív ´û^ÇÝ{}®][þ­}\»Ôua¦×o{e%Ò÷îÒÏoºÛ?ÏC¯ê§BiþÑ_ývêØåZ@XoãÈcZ)àú-X½G'ôk°ú@ëpVßì5ûm«¿ÌúÓ2o~AÌÈ­öK@­Ã@§±¿ºß¨]!ºÙñä+oýñêÀÉZ'¬ÐÒôx]©.õßRþ®´kfWýºÉÿ�Ï %îÅÆNÏÿÓçpåt8r,l|Îßûòë\K+ßHr²¾¬á6Ì»2ßôq[ÿ�x?ùî½ßç­ÛZÇÕ] "$÷-_¶ÑÖðr.�Òf¬íA¦ÏÐ_?Õ¦ûAõKªçbtcÑßv5vôl:uäòÇ?ìæªæúþÙ«Õ\WS±¦Úï¢âö?ú¯oþI­Zø9!ù~¦U#*®³Uzä}¯§tÌ­¾«µÞ®6Ûm«é©Ëôíõ*NÃÔ,æÆ ½Iê£':¾P¿íE­·"Öhmu¸ìý»ý7¿ùlþwþ¶ÛüJòqðjÄÏ·écõMïk VzY§ÖÙýW>«©¶»Yú/Ñ[èú~Q¸2»sk®¼ÂÇÙMD9Án¥uClô.ÉßSëìõ,±QÇ³+çÓVGTl/®àXçÕÛª¥?¢±ø_£ÿ�öÍùU]esý~Æ«¡fv=-pna ¡®VR²öZÌ¬<¦ØÆìÜÖþ¯ûló£Ùú_Z­¢¬¦»#&9ö½½ÀÍ¦·².¤úµWCñÌk=æ?VþiXkY_öZY& É³*k&ÍîÝ^NköUþû¼ì[ZìL¬Ûº-$<ãµÔ]¶k{*õæïõ¬fC_U;F>~E7JUà¯«S¿ãfXeÜâj0XYú'·c½üíËN©NÉIôû2åKªt~¡ÔÍ«ÌpÀü§2Ö¶l©öj­õìcßêú_Î[bä¬Çê]1åöz²GÙ¦Æ{b?î=Þæÿ�èÚ91I[s ÅïÕZâ5ÓË²z³F§ákêï-ä<xþr´Î ñ©'²ÂCqM¨Ï¶ ½°êmpÐüT-êQß@¹Zz gæ§gQÞ"PÕ5}ùõö>ãOIsC0yÝ %E6ÿÔJ±´ôöVÃ«åïós¿ò- j¯óÚ =¥§io0lÆª´¾c}ÝDpF»öÜüÆúÍ,�;dë.#æ8³§S�]¯;¢(ÌoØ2Ü[ùÍcñúwý¼VCj µÚjÒDj5ý*ªó,v¶uJ,Ãx×^ßSûMê5áÿ�¥Äù°s�Ùñôôg¡õrkÇ;pé6IÍxÍ-s¯®I{}6±þÿ�£úEfÁì{2ºÞû[UµVæ6º2^Üröä±´b¹Þ³«nE×õ?X=/­ådô¬pÊ½W>°Û\'écÛíÿ�G·ßüßæ+UYÔ7ÙXÕMÔ}¢ÊÚr=+ë/ý#ë§Ô²ÍÕfº£"Ìl²òZÜl³Ð³ÓÍ§KèÇÈõYv%´3×ô½Ùë?ù¤[2éÂe¸ã3|_U­Çë¬È­õfôR¦Øëjmnô²áëÿ� þ ±ºíZ3ú¯S¿%·3w �¬²©´Ù[v½?½ZoIéX¿eéÈ lý§.Ù`:û\ÛwVßìÔæm.ÉÂÉm´1½n¬í²Ú.!Úê²UÌvUÛ©ÉÅÆý'ó_¡ý¥³Ô|Êº.»Ëëgmà]c[)Ä{iºÏRÖîc(õ}JýMÿ�¥[9[úoNcÙÀÐ=:1díé7ØMnÝÿ�Z\ÖñÑòÅMÅeÏ³åì»Aô²ÆlþWèÝ¿Ôÿ�«}N·qÝ°@ÜG¦À Ú=÷»oÒYôôìì@wVæªoç:FÓþmz_ñ¹+3ë~A·ÝÙÖ8¿Ë¿þIQÃë9oêYkYÝl5ñîÿ�­ØÚîÿ�­¦Î¤îºÆ@öw°Öo}Ð[P:¸ ... Firebug request size limit has been reached by Firebug. ... þM×/0ùÎ^ËmÕô)®w,OS±ôÛýqlv*ìUØ«±Wb®Å]»dÞW]½+g¨ÀÝ¢_ØÑ[g~_iÈA[5ÜäÃñ'Mì|£éÑb!ä(_Äb¨ûÛ=@±kýZe¨?mÈý^¬Çx<Á6»«IzëéEö-à­BF:vÅRUØ«±TÇHòî½¬J±iZuÅìÐA?â1W¦ywþqó;UEú}ÔÐo¥ À¨¼lm4ºÿ�òÈ^Z¸x¼Éæ®&ï- <Æßð¹&b!¾tü¯òù¯ô3{t¿bêàmQÜ4¼ü cºlA"óæg5ØÚ&¸voðkbT°ði>Ùÿ�ÀÄÌÚÆdÒÝkúòA£få*¤ü ²ý=ó$íÚéñpÇÍR¨é7¦F¤Ø°+ot1:  ÓÇ ØêÄ&N,#b@ñ ö(jx÷ÂT2í" Î´òcTN,I÷Íé ½ÝAôâ¯ÿÒ'¦MTÅUmª©Þþ¯á»±ÐNm^~¬ÃvA4A@kJuß£#©>8§Yg¥A"¿<(¦Ì®Ãá#~´þ¸Úh-6ÌéÄµkÛ§ãÄê6( wÄ1[ËÒÕØap±¡<ií®Aë0Ã'H¯¢ky?Ö§Ãø¶ÄÉë½þOkMóv,ÍÆ/Y´ûÒ]*Oú²ñÌ¢àl{þrïÊ£JüÇViµh;S¬öÿ�º¾ü}<±¥á«±Wb®Å]»v*ìUØ«±Tÿ�FóçôtÙ_¸tJHèjâ©¼¿^z>u_åÇ ûé±MKWÔõKq¨ÝKu9ý¹X±/Ue¨êz³]Íþú6¾ågþ_ÿ�|üÒÖx°Ò¿GÂh}[×mþ å'ü&M3ÿ�ç¼ (ÎÞt··+»ZZñî7.çþ§WüQÿ�8éå`?Cy~o0]¦ëqyº;þóþ©ãiÙ/Õ?ç&|Ôb6Þ]°²Ð­FÊ 3ó /ü.¶æïÌ_5ÈV{ýCRçþê¤)ÿ�®åZÏòÎWëÝAÜÍy"EøTm"*Ïä¿)i¢º¼/%`²áê9ãxkÝ ÝÄzUw¸½WI¢ûAqÉ,Ï+Ç¯|¦ssq`Þµâm9A ­k £a]ð-&vÌ�éß4©y£E}©Ã:ô÷ö8È[(È¶ÚÝíçàêCJ²!®¥ßÀP};fFrpur¨&ÌÇTêb¯ÿÓ*§ß`êb«¢¾#õÆÔNvîS+v#a·Ï0K´èå+EE%b¿¿ËJªõjToNßÛ¢P!GòÐa®fuø©?vG4%ÅMwñ)Ì2ó+D5â;·¾JJPj§J`Væëv{Z0}Kf!ùíAÇÌ6´»N¼EÔICÅ/4l?eÍÐÙÌ:ù Ù?:4sùù)m¯Ú/©«èëõ·wnQNî: Þ¢²¢CwÇ9&.Å]»v*ìUØ«±Wbªö×72­ây¤cEHÔ±'ØUy{ò+óK\öú¶¶ïÒâöÉOÞQý¶M3«OùÆ;=2sçO6ÙéY"·¡o¢IcþIãi¥uÿ�¡eò­={4Þ¦ÜÞ²ÆOÓèÛÿ�Â>+²ïüäí&ÛÊ~\±Ñ­R6`íðF#`M±-GÏ>mc ½¾¹ÿ�ãÞÑZ8·ÿ�& ü%¢²ÇòkÏ7íë]¤vhwy.ä¿àG&ûðYO 9¿.¼£ÞaóB<»[Y�[å¿6ÿ�Â¼!hóå~@Ñ|¾Úª*·WíQ·~'üGdëóSÍ¬=: øGmJõøìÈD=w{¬jZöíäsöÝý'"dØ0ÚµOÛ&B:r=2&M±Ã¿ýY-à-+C-Z8ð%´¨ÅQ°'ùU¦(ûi °Å!3k8¯bØYwSãí..NÖnXþ§Ë®×OpNd8.¦*ÿ�ÿÔ-+¶M©í¶ª=@}cêy3EõÂ�Ë0v±D+¡ÀÌ.*^ÿ�N%´w<w�Ó¹=pZ­äví×(¤AR»+ÐwÉ±ÙD+¼>ÜöcöX)%¶Æ4 <Ú{ÿ�L5iF£©ùäYÅj¤É §Ï¦h±·4­(ÒKW ¨ME?ÕlË¬Ê©ù+ù±k¤ko¡êíÃKÕÎó¿÷QÜÂ¤vIGÃ&OAÝ~~þMÞy+\WÓa2y[Q½¼*-¤}ÌGA¿îì²äk§aWb®Å]·o#K»*¨©'ØUùwòó'Ì<[NÐnL-þï}þù8àµz>ÿ�8£«ÃÜy¯ÌZ4«¢UÇû&(<IáL?ç¼¢Üüþe½Oµ³:<+÷ÉÓKgÿ�òîÛÈþQµÓÇDUHØøFöOmÞþe~yy¹Ùm$»ÛF¡ìe?ü>*Nåkù+çíZas¬NÝêf]ýªÔÇ";_Ê#hêyÌ�²õcÿ�ðÁ¹d"òùÇòc@ÛIÒ§p½Ô¸'ýi?æxVÂU¨þzyd0èº|:teâ¼Gü0Ð[=¥æ7ëGTLa¯ü ÐclÆ)¹tØæ²|`ÂãDNDÁ�íM/®Û}øÔ÷È³lNøÊ l4Dq 3\*B±À¨Øáb¬Á~ñS;xØ Sô�­@Øöùétº¬·ÄxäÚ\ß¿ÿÕL©¶6+óÊ5K£úþ¸£­)ÛÅS 6õn í%AN_ÞÝvÅS+8è¡þØdc"«)néì0 *Ø#�WfsÔõ¢ERiö*+î:a,@I¯95w©öÀØýì&ÇèÂ¥çþlÓÞ®Æµ­D«â\ºp3Ã«b¤5S¸Ìáõ¯Ë¿ÏÔ³ÓO|ñkúgËÒ'¢²²e3·Fþú1ÛöÓöpHGêóßp'Pü½ó<Â_éÒ·ªªNô ÅgýR&&,foùÄÌÅ¬WZl±×i=i¿A%ÄE[Î'ë/©®ùMÓas ³íßûÏDckI^@ÿ�kò¨å®y_0]¦æÞÝ-Gn0�?à¤Å4ª¿ß>_&ÛÈÞJdG4È¡Éñ¢ %?ðx-4ºüÊÿ�óX+¦ÙË¥Ú>Á¡[�?ã$¿G4RÁù/çýr__ÌºêcV $/¿±* Hmä·åÎ]{Ty¸îË4Éö FÆÊð¹üçù)å)¥ØÃs2th!ækÿ�%Ä «ÿ�9¨È¦Keå«øÅpîaz¯æµBëR(¬QMái¤DÚ´®^âWÏRÄ×ÃÞ«¬(>3×"dÙ`*éM²6YÒð7Ãi^R»`PáÄ¥¦BÝqE6 ¦ýqHp?~È.�hW`µD 5¥�lP(j\T#áZvÀÉÐTwÅ(»p*)ÓÃ)ì+ûµÌüHt¹ÍÌªSlS©¿ÿÖÇ&Áºb«%#¨ÊóoÓÊ¦`pPÇ|ÖîTæNÔÀØ»|i6­%iCAÔâQ©+AÓ±ÂÅre`AüÍì?)äúJª: Põùä µ) PÐ/ÓøãjKuèvwùÿ�L!6]Y,ÁjËý!%êúr<.¬¡¹úM5L[Ì5½!í%nG¶_ ¸91ÒJc-ö7>Zã¦þL´zâA#:ÕXH¦ÕFitøÄ¥EèÚõG³)c©]ÚÉO÷òð?1Ë(b9¹94ñ<Aó^¯ª{ûØm¡jòæRRË»³{fG,zùcù]¢B%ÕïF«0Ï �}¢Fÿ�¶µà¤sþd~Vùyzd0sQN0-kîàÅ±XÎ±ÿ�9 và®¦ª²ËpåÏü\± SóóVå]BH##û¸?r¢¾ëñ~8Û.XÔ¶W.d¼ºy\êKWé80Ì¶u¬}ñmðq3U«°Ø{`¶À+ªÖJn0ø-+F/ :Ó|T*(Þ¸²øàUÂ#·õvaòïÕIá`Þ>fWèÈ³ É(ÁÛ ö¢â¥3¶*qâÈ#!è2)FDpz8§Ò0°O#JF£¸¹±é ñÅ_ÿ×L¸â­N½q!AÞÐk!FôÉ¥k2 4îñKZªÍS¹Û Ü ¢ÈNË× FÆªWzuï¾)XÌjNÔéJ&Äy>]VEfä(áþbrLW¤Õ÷uSúÎ+MK!?dUö©ÆÔ`õ*ûFëáîp¯$T·�øbC ÖôÁ"±"µík,SÒ9 ¶LM¦XAä²ÔµM6^ÎvP)ÊÛ©sj1;&¿ãÿ�5ðâ×A½Ê àâH)ü×æ{­æ@ò¿«$#R(?Böå«q7"{±,q´¯nï¤Û¡48AÇýÜj¿!Û�]Mò6Ê^øª­7ûñ´ÒÃ Ó¸Ó¦+ÂæCL´¤StÅÔm¾àWl,UXü2%*¨®+$c®UTG¶ßvE-ý\ÆÓm.]« VýEÔì>2µÉ Èé× ¢¡4ö8ð¨GE 4¦|©×Q¶@"%my>qÍ£n*êb¯ÿÐKM¸UÔÅP¤l&^Û?ð9¨W;GøPQ\ô$ýNÄl òêp¥ã}ÀðÂ¡xa#¨'áêk¦`£¹ëóÛ$'â$°®Ëâ~+jêz±3ÖÃÚ¬ ìÌ¦i»*Ãü£RQP*¯Â:J¯¡2)¯ORÖ¡h({üðÅ5==^¦&²ÕæJ)¡-{SÓ%lLV+E*,l2$¤t­7À´¿8 ZF¦A÷ÀR©Q¿ËKm]L¦½ OÏW´R²EÖÕR3ÜSTTöÅU>­]ÈÈ«¤`õú0%Ya «-¸#¶úxa²ï*°âj*Ã­ M»ÓxÚïí¤+Âæ¸É1¶ÔaTãO@×1û³¹Q*O¸fs§wUÔÅ_ÿÙ
image_content   
filename    
hl  en
client  firefox-a
sa  N
rls org.mozilla:en-US:official
biw 1280
bih 335
```

Then it automatically gets the footprint of the image and hit the url:

https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiu_1yAwkNmGIvgyl9GPAFJIIcGNEgGbKu-2DBPorepQnuEtNw1QjGuUUP6AC6j1dpE5ZgksfjnobYOaevvreGlmF0DhTBnHctklgFJaL31aYis2uSPFQAjJ7h9VPXQORv4dfR-8TdG4mJTouAQpAcTlAGdtJ7kNAKRcoBRym35zp87xgJDWoyA99K_1FlKZi0MhAaOeFblCqqYt27n7VI1655d6bWd3XOUWYxkdTsTAyi7dKWtNyE34W3JADhKxrTw6CYnSzie-bERieBBDYMwH7C-7FIP-qcizEJ0ujyGpxOaGlynmRfVj2UNYZ9L-8l9ZRH0KB3VxGHTownyeEn4x1gffsqibJ2tDWOVP3vFE-Fte_13Gw-lDqA8SkXSQhnXl9rNX62oTHgQCGPvr39x9xnvD-dbIl2VzGE4fSb7k0spDW8fzGdQ5yyX8-jZk822FVue1t0qu3R6KSAiy7rsROGjzY3Jp0J4fYA6nRNwe6zo0_16MsOZXUc1a06LFDjpey5ToAkz8eY4pjvOeBKwKopMh3Sd_1486jyo52SM2-ChmZ1LYTJcjFvjhP0W_119Hqo8ejsnQIVAcvlyCc4hJdQcQKbEzWveBmWveEXCPChxTkgHaLidfnYTeN2kOdimZa1TZjNZLjJ4gKZFPsyJjnFA3M2z5ZsbAVvzrDrlksdXj2L3RwperxipZxzegujpLmd9lbkY7zfhNc6k9eyTd4QAgEGta-p-wNQasm8lAS_1M8ZFiRsFTEKEXTMIYSMUjoiZV4pgQBV4E5kobgOAd28XB9cyM8TObGW6idIM0B3hiBtiHwHXI5IUuuUAyv9KDt6X3Devx8wpSb5roo42nVsc72UnV62yLdRTUGqL5vAjjJOsGNNCygavDgLQo_12pBolsDwpSZtF7DYu0gDPWnmhy6hEnRtpGE5V-TcAX8vnwrqSKDGICtOJ1I9cUXXVsnoP7VDrtizU34LDnLSJrtRjBtDhHiZzyi5ROp4W3BDgnCqrcYK0hdRQ5nBQl9f_1hQ1C1zk8-SbhnWF71CiwLmuMBg5uukUArHD3iz37pcI3xjVRy_17NRRbO5Orw3kSG98cg2SBSoMxc9NoUjPcsPgliV6EzEZxUPMMEGQjj0DTqnPaor5W8k2dyZ_1tANb5tCfSe10ONFDuKo82wEpbipzNCFdZax2qIQg1_10psXZZDUbMdyHjjPcwC3cF7W1ezSFYvjJ9dCkR1wfa0QlUxuYgdb3msBvuxjqOr2tChDxY1TzK0ZTwMEfcj7mWIbTD561oGf54AK9NLFRhS3PQ7zhlazzjJxyKUn2uHuLcbGPq5BC954fghqcDGecbMixn6gDDL8rEAstu4rBCVsuDID-DcmrXg_1zh4WE58U8ZVbm4kDv0cJIvq5bE0ik8nYSPmgy10yP4ThUv1S8XpbV3VhRytLvK2TFjYT4BMvShIV4RyErsnSohsmSz8YBhJzJOhMFzhuTRrKOzuwIZz7mpgkC3oC9Qs6qXcqW5SJfKFEc4HluQvFpHgyenYlSf7MEaF93QL6xeVWUXkz-OsZwy5oJUJO-eg_1oUXC2ox9HdG6jOArcx1dWI2MOoNM94sL7yzu8_1VaBB_1vF8f7iiUMqukbUxRIAusOPLbFXFFUJFs0fm94Fj8Uk8_1KUoOI&btnG=Search&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1280&bih=335

In which `tbs` is the variable that holds the image footprint.

My code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload", UriKind.Absolute);
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "image_url", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(""));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "btnG", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Search"));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "encoded_image", GetByteFromImage(e));
            postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "image_content", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(""));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "filename", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(""));

            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();
            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
            webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());

string GetByteFromImage(PhotoResult e)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
        //return imageBytes;
        return e.ChosenPhoto.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length).ToString(); //int
    }
```

What I get in return is the normal Google homepage :(

Comment: Using Fiddler (or similar) how is the HTTP request you're doing different to if you do it via the website?

Comment: http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS "You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services."

Comment: @ephemient Thank you for the info..will try other websites that give me API for that, But that doesn't mean you have to down vote it..it was out of my knowledge....

Comment: I didn't downvote – in fact, I do find it interesting to explore what is *technically* possible.  But you should keep in mind that this isn't an API provided by Google for open use.

Comment: @ephemient API has been depreciated and limited to only 1000 queries a day.. not able to find any other API that can do the same

Comment: Are you referring to the "[Image Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/)" that is browser-only, doesn't support search by image, and is deprecated?  I don't see how that's relevant.  No, what I meant is that while it may be possible and interesting to send your own requests to /searchbyimage/upload, you can't reasonably expect to be able to rely on it.

Comment: @ephemient: Also note that that TOS does not apply now anymore...