# google image search by image file(Not URL , From Endcorded Code )

Tags: google-search, google-image-search

Perhaps, you know that google image search by local image file ..

But, Google does not Support API about only file search.

Just URL or Text search APIs are suppoted..

So i tryed to use URL like this : ( Text = stackoverflow )

https://www.google.co.kr/search?tbm=isch&hl=ko&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=922&q=image&gbv=2&oq=image&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2610l4751l0l4994l6l6l0l0l0l0l143l530l0j4l4l0.frgbld.#hl=ko&newwindow=1&gbv=2&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=**stackoverflow**&oq=**stackoverflow**&aq=f&aqi=g1g-S9&aql=&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24l9.36861l38876l0l39043l13l13l0l4l4l0l355l1319l0j6j0j1l7l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f4b31218673e39ba&biw=1680&bih=922

( file = my local png file )

https://www.google.co.kr/search?tbs=sbi:***AMhZZitnwqdkiC9p9kdEnreZjjbuLJxaCUJ5qd2LHbZcoEo9XHF3GcX2IF_1-Wm_1fMhrkNavPdYSu_1N9DMbghr_1sO2eGfZfmDEZCkV7F0hKlqIMpoZ_1aU2Oz9467IRztBhZyb6nvD2tJdDrLcKK7Nn2lLl9J8XAUY9KFDjQOToAfyZJ4V-aUQAsN-qRdf_1q_1G37i9RiOHVeFOpXz1SXrLFun-6q1IQanS_1l10TL0zND4DKoceZecU1RldThCndiQYKiV1pqZGug_16wqLpw3ZO8o10J14O4Cu7nqGpKHhr3FLk_1NfIfvIzBHzumDe6R5HboVMSihJ1oHRd4FGXh4bzRK5ety36LE_1s7AM7mtds2XdsKrC5KChP8xoAj4WU2TQV9-lMuDvJUyrGlpXOO01_1BazylbqQNhi2qzekzPScqzna3DeXgQ_145869rIg_1YLw1TrbUCHSyrxTH0oPg5Rpeep2owGeenNJ-a_1c-h3THCiU5_1o_1RcnETkJTaC-tJdjU7bycjxxoQc6Jf4Mxcn8L4z8CUyQW1f5Kx0ke7FG5OVAVagojJc5H0Jf0oPlp99ytCFFNUaSI9P0T-XDOfH64j9dW06Pct4Kn4-tqbfdGbpLiWGgD6q2G3orala5iElQDxW54zHcboaMJfc3lJehmn8PyrKas_1HqzyyPq0qndpn2T9yWH7dFo1b0NWnRBYeMwcVnnIw7WlTvYPcdBAr0rzgzBqJsTZnTRH9KJWRRp0uSeYbRbEvxhWXlr5-S76Okde_1hGc5E30KlKG3du_1_1xIlb5LkYykfRNuaFUestUHA3vMmb3Ge0sROFluDAwlD_1znsDSaPVIn0XESh***&num=10&hl=ko&newwindow=1&bih=922&biw=1680

AMhZZ.... here is Code that Encorded from image file

But i can't make this Code from image file.

This is not just binary code to character.

This png file byte length is 187099

But Endcoded code length is not same that.

How can i make that code from image... ?????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, Google does not Support API about only file search.

You already answered the question yourself..., though I'd like to change 'Support' to 'Allow'.

Comment: Does not suppot formally.. But i want to use it another way

Comment: Okay, just discovered Google no longer banns the scripting approach. See this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584808/google-image-search-how-do-i-construct-a-reverse-image-search-url/7586422#7586422 and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309953/using-google-image-search-programmatically for a guide...

Comment: Already i read that answer. But i couldn't find how to making code that be decoded from image.(byte[]) According to other answer, code is generated from Stream that opened FileInputStream. If Read() from Stream, result data is number. And if encode byte[] to URL, possible that getting 'AMhZZi.................' . But i didn't test yet. So, i worndered it's possibility.. from experienced guy.

Comment: If anyone's done it, I doubt it was for fun... You have to figure it out yourself, or *pay* someone to do it for you...